# One way real time communication iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

How can I send the audio/video to my web server from android and iOS devices using Cordova in real time. I only need one way transfer, from phone to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that using webrtc is the way to do it. This is compatible with Android but for iOS you need to wait for webrtc support from apple or implement a JS API that wraps webrtc.

Both [Google's](http://www.webrtc.org/) and [Ericsson's](http://www.openwebrtc.io/) implementations have code examples to get started.